# Swift: Ask user permission for two things, one notification flashes before the other one?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, notifications

So when I run the below code (and open the app for the first time) the location permission request flashes up first and then straight away gets replaced by the notification one. If I answer the notification one then the location one appears. I'm asking how to get rid of the flash of the second notification before the first one.

```
final class ModelController: UIViewController {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var window: UIWindow?
    var mapVC: MapVC?

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
     }
 }
```

My thinking is it's because this called after the UI appears and shouldn't. The modelcontroller is made in viewDidLoad of my rootViewController. I also don't know if that's the right thing to do.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.showsScale = true
    mapView.isPitchEnabled = false

    model = ModelController()
    model?.mapVC = self
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't request those permissions in the init method. You should wait until viewDidAppear. You should also wait until the first one is completed before you present the second. Either using a delegate or completion handler.

Comment: Why should they be in view did appear and not view did load? and I can do this with a completion handler but would it be more helpful with a delegate and how would you do that? Cheers again it does solve my problem.

Comment: glad it helped, when dealing with anything that will be presented to the user its best to wait until the view has appeared. Better user experience. Also, viewDidLoad is just too ealry in the lifecycle to reliably handle UI elements in. Delegate or callback function is really on preference unless a specific situation requires the use of one over the other.